# gnuplot palette: shift/rescale color range

Tags: gnuplot

[image]

I want the color-range to be shifted or rescaled in such a way that "0" is represented by "white".

Right now I simply use

```
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 1 "white", 2 "red")
```

Comment: So, do you want the color range to be symmetric? Would you expect it to go from -2.5 to 2.5 in your example?

Comment: It doesn't need to be symmetric